# Why Asset Browser is missing from Blender 2.92?

Tags: versions, asset-browser

I just downloaded the new version of Blender (2.92) and the "Asset Browser" (which we were all waiting for) is missing. Is this normal for a reason or do I have to do with any settings issue?

Comment: I thought I was the only one facing the issue too. Going through the release notes I guess it's postponed :( Probably another version of 2.92?

Comment: You are right, the developers felt like the feature was not production ready so they pushed it to the next release cycle (hopefully 2.93, but it might be even later)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's simply not ready to be released in 2.92, so they push the asset browser feature back to 2.93.

You should check the 2.93 alpha and play with it, and report if there's bug